# Avoid scientific notation with BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I've a scenario where incoming data (in string form) can come in scientific notation and extra 0s after the decimal point. I'm trying to convert this String to a `BigDecimal` object and eliminate scientific notation and discard extra 0s after Decimal point. I'm using this call:

```
new BigDecimal(new BigDecimal(s).toPlainString()).stripTrailingZeros()
```

For these inputs,

```
"3438836.84782459"
"10000000000.00000000"
"1"
"93650.99015461"
"272333333.33000000"
"0E-8"
"0E-8"
```

When I do `System.out.println` on the resultant `BigDecimal` object, it outputs:

```
3438836.84782459
1E+10
1
93650.99015461
272333333.33
0
0
```

Any clues on how to eliminate scientific notation and extra zeros?

Comment: `272333333.33000000` works as expected. the issue I see is with `"10000000000.00000000"`

Comment: First `stripTrailingZeros()`and then `toPlainString()`: `new BigDecimal(s).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();`. No need to turn a BigDecimal into a string and then back into a BigDecimal.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating too many BigDecimals. The first one you create is formatted as a plain string, which is then lost by being used only as an argument to a second BigDecimal. The second BigDecimal is then printed without being converted to a plain string. All you need to do is:

```
String num = new BigDecimal(s).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
```

Comment: Upstream needs a BigDecimal object but not a string object.

Comment: @sandeep there is no state in BigDecimal for switching between scientific and plain notation. _So there it ends._

Comment: Indeed. BigDecimal is just a value. The notation only comes into play when that value is converted into a String. So what you need to do is find the place where the BigDecimal gets rendered as text, and then change the `toString()` call to a `toPlainString()` call. Note that the `toString()` call may be implicit.

Comment: So in effect, do something like `BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(s).stripTrailingZeros(); System.out.println(num.toPlainString());`.